# How to sum two mysql results row by row?

Tags: mysql, sql

Two mysql select statement are like the following

```
Date    value    
1        1         
2        2        
3        3          
4        4
```

I wonder if there is a way to sum up the value column of these two results row by row when their dates are the same. 
Thanks.

Comment: Did u get these two as a result of two queries??

Comment: @deejay yes. There are two different select results.

Comment: Given your recently deleted 'answer', you might be interested in this discussion: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298950/4751173 I have no part/opinion/stance in that discussion, I just think you might want to read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try like this:

```
select sum(value) from table group by `date`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this....
this is in oracle, please check the syntax for mysql

> select count(value)
>   
> from table_name
>   
> where date in (select distinct(date) from Table)
>   
> group by date